# key using Key.get_or_insert in google app

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

Hi everyone I'm beginner CTF player and I have same lake with  python modules and I face following problem

i dump the file container the flag but it use python to generate it as a hash  using this key

can same one help me to understand this code

```
  key = Key.get_or_insert("key", namespace="default").secret.encode("utf-8")
```

and `secret = ndb.StringProperty()`

Answer (score 0):

logic has not changed, but so the code is easier to comment on

```
key = Key.get_or_insert('key', namespace='default') # if object exists retrieve it, otherwise create and retrieve it 
secret = key.secret # get value of secret field
secret.encode('utf-8') # return an encoded version of the string as a bytes object.
```

Comment: i have in my code   secret = ndb.StringProperty()
what this do

Comment: Most likely this definition is in the model class. And means the following: model `Key` has property with type `String` and the equivalent of this type in `Python` is `str`.This is an explanation in terms of the google app engine. And what it means in the business logic of your program I can not say.